# Task doesnt delete messages, discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So basically this is a lootbox i made for my server, it is supposed to delete on its own.. but when i wake up i check my channel to see 4-5 mesasges, instead of 1! any help? - edit - i should mention when i make x = say 30 minutes and delete time 29 minutes this works fine.

```
x = 180
@tasks.loop(minutes=x)
async def send():
    open('acceptloot.txt', 'w').close()
    response = "Frag has sent supplies into the field, if you're lucky you can get some!"
    channel = bot.get_channel(903563274807808040)
    await channel.send(file=discord.File('lootbox.png'), delete_after=10650)
    message = await channel.send(response, delete_after=10750)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')

@send.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

send.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it the old way, without "delete_after=":

```
message = 'your message' # your message
msg = await bot.send(message) # sends message
await asyncio.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds  
await msg.delete() # delete the message
```

Comment: Ill try that, thanks

Comment: Yeah that didnt work either.. infact more messages appeared and stayed versus the way i had it before.. :( could it be the "wait for x seconds" is just too long?